# How to access pdf from corpus in loop in python

Tags: python, pypdf

I have created a corpus from 2 pdf CV files as below and now i am stuck to fetch the details from the corpus in loop.

I want to fetch the details in loop from corpus.

I have tried below code to create a corpus and using the same in loop to fech the details.

```
mypdf = open('E:\D drive\Resumes\test_CV.pdf', mode='rb')
mypdf2 = open('E:\D drive\Resumes\test1_CV.pdf', mode='rb')

pdf_document = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(mypdf)
pdf_document2 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(mypdf2)

first_page = pdf_document.getPage(0)
first_page2 = pdf_document2.getPage(0)

extract = first_page.extractText()
extract1 = first_page2.extractText()

corpus = [extract, extract1]

#here i am trying to access the corpus: but it returns both pdf data not one by one.
for corp_text in corpus:
    get_all_details(corp_text)
```

It should works as follows:

- from 1st pdf return Example:- 'Text of PDF 1'
- from 1st pdf return Example:- 'Text of PDF 2'

Comment: The question is missing some important information: What does get_all_details do? The syntax looks ok, maybe what is going on is that your code is just spitting everything out without a break between each corpus.

Comment: get_all_details is a function which is used to fetching the entity recognition like Name, skills and email from resume.

Comment: Can you add the output you're receiving?